# How to make a private package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm doing a library. I have three packages:

[image]

Spreadsheet is the main package. The io package is an internal package for **internal use**. Unfortunately, the user can access to them since they are public classes.

I would like to keep this package, since it allows me to separate concepts while programming, but i would like to "hide" these classes to the end user.

What could i do?

Comment: Where are those two Ods* classes used?

Comment: @LppEdd in the Spreadsheet class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you're asking yourself this question! I don't see much attention on this lately.

As `OdsReader` and `OdsWriter` are used only inside the `Spreadsheet` class, just move them inside the `spreadsheet` package, **removing** the `public` visibility keywork. They'll now be accessible only from the `spreadsheed` package's classes.

The solution proposed above, which is over-complicated for your use-case, and which is to use `Java 9+` *modules* (or OSGi - please no!), is not really necessary here, but it's neverthless a step forward in maintaining definitions private and sealed, even to `Reflection` abusers.

---

As a side note, I see you've got an `exceptions` package.
I never recommend doing so, as you'll have to expose those exceptions' constructor to the users of your code, and they'll be able to instantiate them for **no** good reasons.

Move the exceptions inside the packages which uses them, and declare the constructor as package private.

Comment: Yes, in this case, removing the `io` package entirely (and moving those classes over to the main `spreadsheet` package) is a much simpler way to get the desired result. However, this line of thinking generally results in the notion that a project ends up having all classes in one package, which is a rather poor way to try to do intra-project separation of responsibilities.

Comment: @rzwitserloot No it doesn't result in that if the architecture is good. I've been working in massive projects where this tecnique was used and they were perfectly structured. In this case the project is small and it is perfectly suitable. No need to over-engineer (e.g. with Classloaders)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with java9, you can turn this library into a module. See [this jigsaw tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/project-jigsaw-java-modularity).

Modules need to export a package in order for its public members to be accessible from other modules: Simply don't export your internal package, and it won't be visible.

You can also go with something like OSGi, a module system that predates java9. It too has this notion that there's a level beyond public (let's call it 'visible').

A final option is to use classloader shenanigans (where you for example rename your class files to some other extension during the build phase, and have a small bootstrapper in your visible package which creates a classloader that loads classes by looking in the same place as the visible API, and then load files with the alternative extension, and `defineClass` those into being), but that's a drastic step that introduces quite a bit of headache. I wouldn't take it unless you have excellent reasons to go down this rabbit hole.